# How to convert wav to flac?

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio

I am working on windows phone 7 and my captured audio is in WAV format.  I want to convert to FLAC format as the back end server accepts only FLAC. Is it possible to do it in windows phone 7. If it cannot be done on the phone, is there a web API to which i can do a http post for WAV and it will return me in FLAC ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to either convert the files online or on a computer, rather than your phone. There are a lot of applications that can do the conversion on your computer, but I only saw a few online resources for doing the wav to flac conversion - one example being [Convert.Files](http://www.convertfiles.com/convert/audio/WAV-to-FLAC.html). I don't think it offers what you're looking for in terms of a web API, but you should be able to write some code to post your files/data to the site's form.